# Delete individual products/boxes with checkboxes won't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am was trying to delete one or more product-list tables with checkbox option, however I cannot seem to make delete.php to work, whenever I click DELETE, it takes me to http://localhost:3000/delete.php?delete=, I have attempted several solutions that were provided in google searches, but nothing seems to work, here is the code...

index.html

```
<nav>
      <button class="add-btn" id="addBtn"> <a href="product-add.php">ADD</a> </button>
      <form action="delete.php">
      <input  type="hidden" id="delete" name="delete">
         <button type="submit" >Delete</button>
         </form>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="product-list-wrapper">
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
      <div class="div-box">
        <table>
          <form action="delete.php">
          <tbody>
          <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $product['SKU'] ?>"/>
            <?php if ($counter %2 != 0) : ?>
              
              <tr class="content">
                <td><?php echo $product['SKU'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Price'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Size'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Weight'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Dimension'] ?></td>
              </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </tbody>
          </form>
        </table>
        </form>
      </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </section>
```

and delete.php

```
<?php


/** @var $pdo \PDO */

require_once 'database.php';


if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM skandi Where sku = :sku');
            $statement->bindParam(':sku', $chechbox);
            $statement->execute();
        }
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
}

 ?>
```

Comment: You're missing `method="POST"` on your form opening tag

Comment: A silly mistake on my part, however now, whenever I click delete, nothing happens...

Comment: Because your form does not contain the submit button. Whenever you click on your button nothing happens. The button is no member of your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this, it might help someone in a similar situation, so here's how I've done it...

```
  <header>
    <h2>Product List</h2>
    <nav>
      <button class="add-btn" id="addBtn">ADD</a> </button>
      <button type="submit" id="deleteBtn" form="delete_form" name="delete" value="delete">Delete</button> <---Placed form="delete_form" here--->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="product-list-wrapper">
    <form method="POST" action="delete.php" id="delete_form">
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
        <?php if ($counter % 2 != 0) : ?>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="content">
                <th> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $product['id'] ?>"> </th>
                <td style="visibility: hidden"><?php echo $product['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['SKU'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['Price'] ?>$</td>
                <?php if ($product["productType"] == "dvd") : ?>
                  <td> Size: <?= $product['Size'] ?> MB </td>
                <?php elseif ($product["productType"] == "book") : ?>
                  <td> Weight: <?= $product['Weight'] ?> KG </td>
                <?php elseif ($product["productType"] == "furniture") : ?>
                  <td> Dimensions: <?= $product['Height'] ?> x <?= $product['Length'] ?> x <?= $product['Width'] ?> CM </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </form>
  </section>
```

and the delete.php...

```
$id = $_POST['id'] ?? null;

if(!$id) {
    header('location: index.php ');
    exit;
}

            $statement = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM skandi where id = :id');
            $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $statement->execute();

            header('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code. Let me explain you the changes:

- Don't put `<a>` inside a `button`. You can use `css` to style your links to look like buttons.
- the delete `button` in your `nav` won't do anything beacuse you're not adding anything in those inputs.
  that's why when you submit that form it just take you to `http://localhost:3000/delete.php?delete=` with no information.
- In your `foreach` loop, you're creating a new `form` for every `product` individually.
  This is not the best way to do it (And I'm sure is not what you want).
  You should create a single `form` outside the `foreach` and add all the `input`s to it.
  Then you can submit it with just one click.

To make this work you have 2 options (or both at the same time)

**Method 1:** Place a "delete" `button` inside the form where you have the `checkbox` inputs.
**Method 2:** Use `javascipt` to submit the form with the `button` in your `nav`.

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <a id="addBtn" class="add-btn" href="product-add.php">ADD</a> <!-- Delete the button wrapping <a> tag -->
        <button id="deleteBtn" type="button">Delete</button><!-- Empty form won't do anything, so you can just leave the button with an ID attribute -->
    </nav>
</header>
<section class="product-list-wrapper">
    <!-- form outside the foreach loop -->
    <form id="deleteForm" method="POST" action="delete.php"> <!-- Add missing method="post" -->
        <input  type="hidden" id="delete" name="delete">
        <div class="div-box">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
                        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $product['SKU'] ?>"/>
                        <?php if ($counter %2 != 0) : ?>
                        <tr class="content">
                            <td><?php echo $product['SKU'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['Name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['Price'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['Size'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['Weight'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['Dimension'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Delete</button> <!-- Submit the form normally -->
    </form>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteBtn');
    let deleteForm = document.getElementById('deleteForm');
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        deleteForm.submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer, it's helpful for understanding how things work, however the rules of the task are such that the buttons must remain in the nav section... 
Yep, I would love for the loop to be written like this, however it scrambles my div box completely, and I have 4, 5  checkboxes for each row in the table...

Comment: I understand. Did the Javascript option worked for you? Also, can you update your question with the rest of the updated code so I can help you?

Comment: Hi, so sorry for the late answer... So I reverted to the previous code, the JS did not work, and this is what it looks like with the form outside the loop... https://i.postimg.cc/6yxkHHYh/exhibit1.png 
It should be 3 boxes, maybe it's a CSS issue. I'm pretty new to php and I am doing this as a task for a job interview...

Comment: @Bork I have a typing error in my javascript example. It's `deleteForm` not `delete`. That's why the form was not been submitted

Comment: Nope, I thought I was writing it wrong, but I copy, pasted this whole segment, unfortunately not working...